# NestJS and Prisma ORM : cleanest way to exclude password from response while allow it in requests?

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I'm using NestJS with Prisma ORM and kinda of struggling with the use of `@Exclude()` decorator because when I add it on my `UserDto`, it also excludes the password from the incoming requests, so Prisma does not access to the password.

For now, I've done this, but I'm sure it is not the cleanest way to do it.

### User DTO

```js
export class CreateUserDto {
  // [...]

  // Not @Exclude() here because otherwise I don't get Passwords from Incoming requests
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;
}

export class UserDto extends CreateUserDto {

  @Exclude()
  password: string;
}
```

### User Service

```js
  // [...]
  async create(userData: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    userData.password = await argon.hash(userData.password);

    try {
      const createdUser = await this.prismaService.user.create({
        data: userData,
      });

      // *** DIRTY PART ***
      return plainToClass(UserDto, createdUser) as User;
      // *** DIRTY PART ***
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
        if (e.code === 'P2002')
          throw new ConflictException('A user with this email already exists');
      }

      throw e;
    }
  }
  // [...]
```

### User Controller

```js
  // [...]
  @Post('register')
  async register(@Body() userData: CreateUserDto) {
    console.log(userData);
    return this.userService.create(userData);
  }
  // [...]
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

This is currently an issue being worked on by Prisma.

You can follow the issue at: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5042

**There are two solutions to this problem:**

Manually stripping the password from any response of type User:

```
async findOne(userId: string) {
const admin = await this.prismaService.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    id: userId,
  },
});

const { id, email, phoneNumber, createdAt, updatedAt } = admin;

return { id, email, phoneNumber, createdAt, updatedAt };

 }
```

Create a global interceptor to remove all 'password' values:

```
import { Injectable, 
         NestInterceptor, 
         ExecutionContext, 
         CallHandler } from '@nestjs/common';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';

 @Injectable()
 export class RemovePasswordInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
        intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
            return next.handle().pipe(
                   map((value) => {
                                   value.password = undefined;
                                   return value;
                                  }),
                                 );
                                }
                               }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is write a function that will exclude that field from the response only, and apply it to my routes using interceptor

```
import { isArray, isDefined } from 'class-validator';

export function sanitize<T>(source: T, field: string): T {
  if (typeof source !== 'object') return source;
  if (isArray(source)) {
    for (const item of source as any[]) {
      sanitize(item, field);
    }
  }
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(source) as any) {
    if (!isDefined(value)) continue;
    if (typeof value === 'object') source = sanitize(value, field);
    if (key === field) {
      delete source[key];
    }
  }
  return source;
}
```

and this is my interceptor

```
import {
  CallHandler,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { tap } from 'rxjs';
import { sanitize } from '../utils/field-sanitizer';

@Injectable()
export class PasswordSanitizerInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler<any>) {
    return next.handle().pipe(tap((data) => sanitize(data, 'password')));
  }
}
```

then you can apply to any routes you like, in this approach I'm manage to exclude the password in nested object too!